# Disappeared without a trace -- the flip side of the issue

Tags: death

We just had a question about how people are declared dead when they disappear without a trace.  That got me thinking about the reverse situation:

Someone leaves behind a power of attorney and says "I'm leaving to go be with [secretive cult], don't try to find me."  They're receiving some sort of lifetime payment which is going into a joint account.  Nothing is ever heard from them again.

From the answers to the other question it seems impossible for them to be declared dead, do the payments continue forever?

Answer (score 1):

### Different question, same answer

[What happens if someone dies without a trace?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67856/what-happens-if-someone-dies-without-a-trace/67857)

As answered there, when a court or a register believes that a person is likely dead, they can issue a death certificate.

So, for the scenario of someone who has not disappeared but has instead knowingly withdrawn from society, the same rules apply.

For the example of a lifetime annuity, the person paying for it can apply to the court providing evidence that they believe will convince the court the person is likely dead. They would need to explain the efforts that they have made to contact the person and how they have been unsuccessful and the basis on which they believe the person is dead - like ... they would now be 112 years old if they weren't.

Comment: The answer to the other question have multiple requirements that aren't met in my scenario.

Comment: @LorenPechtel not at all. The fundamental requirement is that the court or register is satisfied that they are dead.